# Change values in a key during a compareTo in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

there is a way to change the value of an instance variable during the compareTo of a mapreduce job with a custom key ? (i have some problems because it reads and write data with two methods = readFields(DataInput in) and write(DataOutput out) , and it writes the object into the framework only the first time and i can't modify it for the rest of the process)

i have this code for my compareTo of my custom key

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MultipleText m1) {
        for(Writable one : m1.getChiavi().keySet())
        {
            if(this.chiavi.keySet().contains(one))
            {
                if(this.chiavi.get(one).equals(m1.getChiavi().get(one)))
                    if(!strutturaTab.equals(m1.getStrutturaTab()))
                    {
//                      if(this.chiavi.size()>m1.getChiavi().size())
//                          m1.setChiaviComplete(this.chiavi);
//                      else if(this.chiavi.size()<m1.getChiavi().size())
//                          this.setChiaviComplete(m1.getChiavi());
                        return 0;
                    }
                return 1;
            }
            return 2;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

the commented lines are the lines that doesen't works

when it goes to reduce phase the method getChiaviComplete() returns null , that is the value when i initialized and wrote (using write(DataOutput out) method) the instance variable (chiaviComplete)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the Key during comparing, because the record that being compared is just a copy of the record. Changing the object won't change the record.